# Using <context:component-scan base-package /> in annotation based configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-annotations

I have gone through different resources but still I am not getting my work done. Here is my Spring annotation based configuration :-

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-mysql.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "org.baeldung.persistence" })
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

public PersistenceJPAConfig() {
    super();
}

// beans

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.baeldung.persistence.model" });

    final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

    return em;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName")));
    dataSource.setUrl(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.url")));
    dataSource.setUsername(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.user")));
    dataSource.setPassword(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass")));

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

final Properties additionalProperties() {
    final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    // hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers",
    // "true");
    return hibernateProperties;
}
```

}

I have my controller class in `org.baeldung.persistence.controller` package and denoted `@Controller` at the top of the class. Still I am getting `404` error when I access the URL `/products`. Here is my controller class

```
@Controller
public class ProductViewController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(@ModelAttribute("product") final Product product)     {
    final ProductServiceImpl productServiceImpl = new ProductServiceImpl();
    if (productServiceImpl.create(product)) {
        return "Product with product name : " + product.getProduct_name() + "Has been created";
    } else {
        return "Error while creating the product record";
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the exception that gives the 404?

Comment: It says `The requested resource is not available.`

Comment: Am I doing the correct way by defining `@ComponentScan({"org.baeldung.persistence" })` ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: So I can't figure out where it went wrong. Can you help me fix this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinnce your controller class is in `org.baeldung.persistence.controller` package, you have to scan components in this package

```
@ComponentScan({ "org.baeldung.persistence.controller" })
```

you will also need to add `@EnableWebMvc` in PersistenceJPAConfig class

```
@EnableWebMvc
```

Comment: I have added those LOC but still I get the same error. Do I have to configure anything else like web.xml or dispatcher servlet to run the project in the browser? I haven't created anything for that

Comment: Yes you need to create servlet3 initializer that will extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

Comment: for your reference, have a look on this http://www.tutorialsdesk.com/2016/02/spring-mvc-security-with-hibernate_24.html